# What happens when calling base functions from derived classes?

Tags: c++

Well my question is a bit trickier.
Let's say I have three classes like so:

```
    class GrandFather
    {
    public:
        virtual int DoSomething()
        {
            return 3;
        }   
    };

    class Father : public GrandFather
    {
    };

    class Child : public Father
    {
    public:
        virtual int DoSomething()
        {
            Father::DoSomething();      
        }   
    };
```

I have found in some references, that when calling a base function, the whole virtual mechanism isn't used, and name mangling takes place.

Now I want to know how this could be done.

The Child class has a pointer to its own vtable, which will indicate that upon calling `DoSomething()` the implementation of the child is called.

The Father class has a pointer to its own vtable as well, which will indicate that upon calling `DoSomething()` the implementation of GrandFather is called.

When I use `Father::DoSomething()` inside of Child, it should call `GrandFather::DoSomething()`,
but how can Child tell where the function is?

If name mangling is really used, then how? because there is no function with that name (something like `_Father_DoSomething(this)`).

Child must access the Father's vptr in order to get to `GrandFather::DoSomething()` , which as much as I know, he cannot.

This has been bothering me for quite some time, so I will appreciate the help very much.
thanks :)

Comment: What did you try! Compilation errors, runtime errors, be specific!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you explicitly qualify the member function, you are saying you want to call that particular function in that particular class, and the virtual calling mechanism isn't used.  Virtual calls only take place when you call a member function without qualifying it, it which case it uses the virtual mechanism to make the decision about which class's member function to use.

The fact that calling `Father::DoSomething` calls GrandFather::DoSomething is due to inheritance, which is a separate mechanism.  If you refer to a member of the derived class and it isn't there, it goes up one level and looks in the base class for it.  No virtual call is necessary there.

Comment: Whenever you explicitly qualify, you're telling the compiler to do the name lookup starting at that point.  As in his example, the function may not be in the class he specifies, but in a parent of that class.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Yes, good point.  I've added some information about inheritance to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `Father::DoSomething` from `Child` the compiler used compile time information to work out what to call. Because there isn't a version in `Father` it knows to call the one in `GrandFather` as it's the version that is effectivly in scope within `Father`.

When an overridden method calls down to a base implementation the vtable isn't used. The vtable is only used when you call a method via a pointer or reference. This is how all polymorphism is achieved in C++.

Name mangling doesn't have anything to do with this. Name mangling is basically how a method name is encoded so give a unique name for a method/function. No two methods/functions will have the same mangled name.

Comment: The vtable (assuming that that is the implementation technique used) is only used if 1) the function found by static lookup is virtual, and 2) the function name is unqualified.  In practice, the compiler will also forgo using the vtable if it can determine the dynamic type (which will always be the case if there are no pointers or references).

Comment: @JamesKanze - yes, but when calling the base class function from within the overridden function there's no need to use a vtable as the correctly implementation can be determined statically.

Answer (score 1):

When a qualified name is used to name the function, the function
called is determined at compile time, using the static type of 
the expression, and the name lookup starts at the location given
by the qualifier.  Since the function to be called is determined
entirely by static lookup, there is no need to access any vtable
at all.

Answer (score 1):

The g++ file_name.cpp -S command could provide enough info to have all vtable-related issues clear. Please check .s file produced:

Child has own vtable that contains Father vtable that, in own turn, contains vtable for GrandFather:

```
vtable for Child:
    Child::DoSomething()
    vtable for Father

vtable for Father:
    GrandFather::DoSomething()
    vtable for GrandFather

vtable for GrandFather:
    GrandFather::DoSomething()
```

> When I use Father::DoSomething() inside of Child, it should call
>   GrandFather::DoSomething(), but how can Child tell where the function
>   is?

vtable for Father has reference to the GrandFather::DoSomething(), so calling Father::DoSomething() you are actualli invoking GrandFather::DoSomething()

Answer (score 1):

1. "Name mangling" has absolutely nothing to do with it. The technique known as "name mangling" belongs to completely different and irrelevant area. I don't know where you got the idea to involve it here.
2. Classes do not have any "pointers to vtable". Only *specific objects* (aka instances) of class types might have such pointers. Don't mix *classes* and *objects of class type*. In any case, "vtable pointers" is an implementation detail that does not exist at language level. It is completely unnecessary for understanding the behavior of the code at language level.
3. In your example you don't have any objects at all. You simply declared a bunch of classes. For this reason, it is to early to be taking about any "pointers to vtables". You don't have any pointers to any vtables in what you posted.
4. When it comes to the matter of `Father::DoSomething()` call, the issue of any "virtual tables" does not come into the picture at all, even as an implementation detail. `Father::DoSomething()` call uses a *qualified* name of the target function. Such qualified calls are always resolved directly, without involving any vtables. I.e. by doing `Father::DoSomething()` you are explicitly asking the compiler to ignore any polymorphism (ignore any "vtables") and directly perform a compile-time name lookup for name `DoSomething` in class `Father`. According to the rules of name lookup it will find function `GrandFather::DoSomething()` and call it.
5. If you actually declare an object, like

   ```
   Child child;
   ```

   then you will have a `GrandFather` subobject embedded into `Father` subobject embedded into the above `Child` object. All "vtable pointers" in those nested objects will point to the vtable of `Child` (in fact, in a typical implementation all these nested objects will share a single vtable pointer).

   Now if you call

   ```
   child.DoSomething()
   ```

   this call will be resolved in accordance with vtable of `Child` and dispatched to `Child::DoSomething()` (most compilers will actually be smart enough to optimize the code and dispatch the call directly). However, as I said above, the qualified call to `Father::DoSomething` from inside `Child::DoSomething` is unconditionally performed directly, as you asked. It doesn't care about any vtable pointers. It just goes straight to `GrandFather::DoSomething()`.

That's all there is to it.